# Am getting Transient error while using mongodb + Nodejs on Openshift online container 4.2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

I have a mongoservice running on openshift online, i also have a nodejs app running. However, the application does not seem to connect to mongodb on openshift but it works well on my windows 10 locally

Here is the complete log from Openshift console terminal.

```
OLA server running on port 8080
Not Connected to Database, ERROR!  { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at createConnection (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:559:14)
    at connect (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:973:11)
    at makeConnection (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at Socket.err (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
MongoDB connection error: { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at createConnection (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:559:14)
    at connect (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:973:11)
    at makeConnection (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at Socket.err (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at last. Just had to replace **127.0.0.1:27017** with **openshiftmongodbservicename:27017** in the mongo connection URL

Changed

```
mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname
```

to

```
mongodb://username:password@openshiftmongodbservicename:27017/dbname
```

Hope this helps someone in future.